# How to get twitter bootstrap working in plunker?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, plunker

This should be easy, but I'm constantly failing to get a simple bootstrap example working in plunker.

I have this simple bootstrap example in [my plunker project](https://plnkr.co/edit/BwwwWMK6DTyh3Xh3na0l):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

If I hit the Run button it looks like bootstrap isn't available. Inspecting the divs with Chrom clearly shows, that bootstrap is there. But there's no formatting at all.

If I hit the preview button everything is formatted as expected.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: If you increase preview window then you will see it the way you want.. Happens because window width falls under smaller device width..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview window is not wide enough.

Try using `col-xs-1` or `col-sm-8` instead of `col-md-1`..!:-)

Comment: Rather than `instead`, use the respective classes for smaller devices `and` classes for larger ones.